# Regex to find and replace extentions for anchor with specific class

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have got a project for which I need to translate the urls from wikispaces format to the wordpress. What I am looking for is to replace

> .html

with

> /

where the text is in the following format

```
<a class="identifier-class" href="<some_variable_url>.html>......</a>
```

with

```
<a class="identifier-class" href="<some_variable_url>/>......</a>
```

What string replacement regex can I use to replace it in Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should always show what you have tried so far. 
Second of all, the answer is:

in **Find what** field you put this:

```
a class="identifier-class" href="([^"]*?)\.html*?"
```

What is enclosed in **()** means capture this string. This is the string you need. That's why I added **.html** outside. The reason you see `\.html` instead of `.html` is that . (dot) is a special character in regex patterns, and needs to be escaped in order to be treated like a simple dot.

And in **Replace with** you write this:

```
a class="identifier-class" href="$1/"
```

**$1** in this case is the string captured inside **()** (see explanation above)

I tested on the following string (please notice there is also a link with **another-identifier-class-not-me** which will be skipped)

```
<a class="identifier-class" href="/some_variable_url/cucu.html"/>......</a> <a class="identifier-class" href="/anotehr_variable_url/mucu.html"/>......</a> 
<a class="another-identifier-class-not-me" href="/some_variable_url/cucu.html"/>......</a>
<a class="identifier-class" href="/anotehr_variable_url/mucu.html"/>......</a> <a class="identifier-class" href="/some_variable_url/cucu.html"/>......</a>
<a class="identifier-class" href="/anotehr_variable_url/mucu.html"/>......</a>
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if there are more than 1 `href="..."` in a line.

Comment: @Toto I don't know what you tried but it does work. I just tested.

Comment: For example on a string like: `<a href="<some_variable_url>.html">...</a> <a href="<some_variable_url>.html">...</a> `

Comment: @Toto You were right, thank you! I missed that twice: on my first test, on the second test -  when you first pointed it out. Sorry for that... I corrected the answer.

Comment: @besciualex I have multiple anchor tags and I only need to replace where anchor contains the identifier class.

Comment: @user869375 Please check updated answer, and don't forget to Upvote our answers. We took from our time to help you. Good day! :)

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<a class="identifier-class" href="[^"]+\K\.html(?=")`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<a class="identifier-class"  : literally
href="[^"]+ : search for href=", followed by 1 or more any character that is not double quote "
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
\.html      : literally ".html"
(?=")       : lookahead, make sure we have '"' after
```

Comment: I have multiple anchor tags and I only need to replace where anchor contains the identifier class.